# d3.js - Zoom and Center on Click - Map scales, points do not

Tags: svg, maps, d3.js, zooming, map-projections

I'm adapting the zoomable and clickable map found http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206340 at to plot some points and do some other things.  Right now, I'm trying to make it such that on the zoom and click actions, the plotted points also move / honor the zoom.  I'm not sure what in the code here is wrong, since I seem to be calling the red.circle and blue.circle objects in the zoom + click -- can anyone identify the issue?  Thanks!  data.csv is formatted as follows:

```
lon_0,lat_0,lon_1,lat_1
-122.1430195,37.4418834,-122.415278,37.778643
-122.1430195,37.4418834,-122.40815,37.785034
-122.4194155,37.7749295,-122.4330827,37.7851673
-122.4194155,37.7749295,-122.4330827,37.7851673
-118.4911912,34.0194543,-118.3672828,33.9164666
-121.8374777,39.7284944,-121.8498415,39.7241178
-115.172816,36.114646,-115.078011,36.1586877
```

and here is the d3.js script.

```
.background {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all; 
}

#states path {
  fill: #aaa;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

#states path:hover {
  stroke: white;
}

</style>
<body>
<script>

var width = 1920/2,
    height = 1000/2;

var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .scale(width)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .translate(projection.translate())
    .scale(projection.scale())
    .scaleExtent([height, 50 * height])
    .on("zoom", zoom);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("style", "stroke:black; stroke-width:2px");

var states = svg.append("g")
    .attr("id", "states")
    .call(zoom);

var dataset = [];


states.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("us-states.json", function(json) {

  states.selectAll("path")
      .data(json.features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .on("click", click);

 d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
   states.selectAll(".blue.circle")
     .data(data)
     .enter()
     .append("circle")
     .attr("cx", function(d) {
               return projection([d["lon_0"], d["lat_0"] ])[0];
               })
     .attr("cy", function(d) {
               return projection([d["lon_0"],d["lat_0"] ])[1];
               })
     .attr("r", 5)
     .attr("class", "blue circle")
     .style("fill", "blue");
   states.selectAll(".red.circle")
     .data(data)
     .enter()
     .append("circle")
     .attr("cx", function(d) {
               return projection([+d["lon_1"], +d["lat_1"] ])[0];
               })
     .attr("cy", function(d) {
               return projection([+d["lon_1"],+d["lat_1"] ])[1];
               })
     .attr("r", 5)
     .attr("class", "red circle")
     .style("fill", "red");
  });

});

function click(d) {
  var centroid = path.centroid(d),
      translate = projection.translate();

  projection.translate([
    translate[0] - centroid[0] + width / 2,
    translate[1] - centroid[1] + height / 2
  ]);

  zoom.translate(projection.translate());

  states.selectAll("path").transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("d", path);

  states.selectAll("red.circle").transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("d", circle);
  states.selectAll("blue.circle").transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("d", circle);       

}

function zoom() {
  projection.translate(d3.event.translate).scale(d3.event.scale);
  states.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);
  states.selectAll("red.circle").attr("d", path);
  states.selectAll("blue.circle").attr("d",path);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you're setting the co-ordinates of the circles when you load the map, so when you click the zoom function, your circles are displayed but are not using the same co-ordinates - i think - it will help if you can create a http://bl.ocks.org to see this.

perhaps this could be of help http://bl.ocks.org/nkhine/3150901 only UK, US and Afganistan works, but i am basically re-projecting the secondary map to fit the new zoom level.